# How to change particular image in recycler view after clicking

Tags: android, uiimageview, android-recyclerview

I want to change respective image of clicked item in recycler view. Now whats happening is if i click on item 2 image is changing at random item position in the list

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder> {

private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<CRMbean> mDataset;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
static Context mContext;
private List<String> mtList ;


public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> filteredList, CRMactivity crMactivity) {
    mtList = filteredList;

}

public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View
        .OnClickListener {
    public static ImageView testImage;
    TextView name;
    TextView regId;
    TextView roomNo;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        regId = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.reg_id);
        roomNo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.roomno);
         testImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);


        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);

    }
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<CRMbean> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}





@Override
public MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);

    DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.regId.setText(mDataset.get(position).getRegId());
    holder.roomNo.setText(mDataset.get(position).getRoomNo());

}

public void addItem(CRMbean dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
    mDataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}


public interface MyClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
```

}

the above is for adpater of recyclerview

```
 ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener
            (new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);

                    MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder.testImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_icon_fill);
                    //getInformation(position);

                }
            });
```

the above code is for OnclickListener

Comment: (MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder.testImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_icon_fill); ) in place of doing this change mtList.get(postion)  item and modify it and call  method notifydatasetchanged() of adapter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this,

```
class CRMbean{
   public boolean isImageChanged;
  public boolean isImageChanged() {
        return isImageChanged;
    }

    public void setImageChanged(boolean imageChanged) {
        isImageChanged = imageChanged;
    }
}
```

On BindHolder do it like,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.regId.setText(mDataset.get(position).getRegId());
    holder.roomNo.setText(mDataset.get(position).getRoomNo());
if(mDataset.get(position).isImageChanged()){
    holder.testImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_icon_fill);
}else{
     holder.testImage.setImageResource("You Default Image");
}
}
```

on Adapter write this method

```
public void changeImage(int index) {
 mDataset.get(position).setImageChanged(true);
   notifyItemChanged(index)

}
```

On Item click Of Recyleview

```
 (MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener
            (new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);

               MyRecyclerViewAdapter.changeImage(position);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the image value in the object at the clicked position and 
Call `notifyItemChanged(position)`.Also handle the image change in `Bindviewholder(ViewHolder holder,position)` method of the Adapter.

Comment: no. image is still changing at random position after onClick

Comment: If i click on item2 image is changing at item6

Answer (score 1):

in `onBindViewHolder` add following code:

testImage.setTag(holder);

then, in onClick add this code to change image:

```
MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder  yourHolderObj = (MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder)((ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo)).getTag();

yourHolderObj.testImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_icon_fill);
```

Comment: no. image is still changing at random position after onClick

Comment: If i click on item2 image is changing at item6

Comment: set your onclick listner in onBindViewHolder on outer most parent layout of your view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 @Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder,int position {

holder.name.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
holder.regId.setText(mDataset.get(position).getRegId());
holder.roomNo.setText(mDataset.get(position).getRoomNo());
holder.testImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.log)
holder.testImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         name.setImageResource(Anything you want);


}
```