# How to change image in Recyclerview on specific arraylist of images?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having recyclerview of arraylist images like this
[image]
, and it's working, now whatever i click the image, it will change to `newimages` on `itemClicked` method, How do i do that?
Note: `itemClicked` method is implemented from adapter recyclerview

```
public List<Information> getData(){
        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] iconList = {R.drawable.th_ok,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small,R.drawable.thbg_small};
        String[] titles = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
        String[] subtitles = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J" };
        for(int i=0;i<titles.length && i<iconList.length;i++)
        {
            Information current = new Information();
            current.iconth = iconList[i];
            current.subtitle = subtitles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable newimages = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.th_ok);

//      startActivity(new Intent(treasure.this,MapsActivity.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was adopted from this one : [How to change particular image in recycler view after clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959366/how-to-change-particular-image-in-recycler-view-after-clicking)
just add:

```
adapter.changeImage(position);
```

on `itemClicked` method, after you follow that link answer. that should work